# Is there a reliable recursive formula for a simple moving average (moving mean)?

Tags: mean

I've tried some recursive moving average formulae (to reuse a previous output instead of summing the whole `n`-long set for every `i`) I've managed to find but none of them produces the same results as a bare moving mean does. Is there a reliable recursive formula which would produce exactly (or almost exactly) the same output as a bare moving mean?

Comment: It seems that you are using some kind of software. If this is true, please tell us, it is easier to give an answer then.

Comment: I program in Scala.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just try to remove the last value of the window and add the new one.

If

$$MA(t)=\frac{1}{w}\sum\limits_{i=t-w+1}^t{y_i}$$

then

$$MA(t+1)=MA(t)+\frac{y(t+1)-y(t-w+1)}{w}.$$

Comment: Yes, this formula looks reasonable but somehow the result I get is always below the non-recursive moving mean. And the difference looks constant. Perhaps I have a bug in my code, the difference would hardly be constant otherwise.

Comment: The possible reason might be the following. If the values of y(t) are relatively small and w is big, divisions for sum(y(t))/w and (y(t)+y(t-w))/w have different precision orders. (for example if y(t) is approximately 0.001, and n is 10000, division 0.001/10000 is less accurate, compared to 10/10000). Then if you add real numbers with different precisions, the smaller one is truncated.

Comment: This formula is not correct because it *subtracts* the new value rather than adds it!

Comment: Yes, you was right. Just corrected it.

Comment: Thank you! (+1).  I have taken the liberty of also correcting a slight indexing error.

Answer (score 1):

```
double mean(const double F, const double C, unsigned int *n)
{
  return (F*(*n)+C)/(++*n);
}
```

`F` is the old average number, `C` is a new addition to the avarage. `*n` is the number of values in `F`. This does not need a buffer.

Comment: This is a way of updating a *cumulative* mean but not a moving mean: that's why no buffer is needed.